# How to determine our system is following X86 or X64. architecture

Tags: x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

How  do i determine my system is following which configuration.
**X86 or X64** ?

Ps:I am not talking about 32bit or 64bit operating system but the instruction set srchitecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **x64 means 64-bit architecture**
- **x86 means 32-bit architecture**
- The reason the 32-bit architecture isn't called "x32" is because it
  harks back from the old days of the Intel "xxx86" processors (8086 /
  80286 / 80386).
- The "x86" moniker distinguished earlier versions of Windows that
  could run on the "xxx86" Intel CPUs from those that could run on
  RISC-based MIPS and Alpha processors.

[Wikipedia-X86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Answer (score 1):

64-bit app uses more memory for application than 32-bit . So application should have more advantage

Comment: How do i determine it is X86 or X64 ?